# @IndexedEmbedded and @ContainedIn relationship not working

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, hibernate-search

Data from one index "A" should be updated to another index "B" while using the @IndexedEmbedded and @ContainedIn relationship. But still the entity containing the @IndexedEmbedded annotation is not updated with data from entity containing the @ContainedIn annotation.

Not sure, what I'm doing wrong. But as per documentation, this should work. Once I update A the same should reflect on B.

The Elastic DB structure is, I believe fine. But the index is empty.

**But the HibernateMasterSearchIndex is updated when I manually save the object to Elastic DB like**

```
fullTextSession.save(localBasclt0900TO.getHibernateMasterSearch());
```

will I've to always persist/delete/update the data like above. If yes, then why the documentation of hibernate search says, it will work automatically.

I believe this is not the correct way of doing this.

### Any ways, below is the code

```
    {
  "hibernatemastersearchindex" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "com.csc.pt.svc.data.to.HibernateMasterSearch" : {
        "dynamic" : "strict",
        "properties" : {
          "basclt0100TO" : {
            "properties" : {
              "clientname" : {
                "type" : "text"
              },
              "cltseqnum" : {
                "type" : "long",
                "store" : true
              },
              "firstname" : {
                "type" : "text"
              },
              "longname" : {
                "type" : "text"
              },
              "midname" : {
                "type" : "text"
              }
            }
          },
          "basclt0900to" : {
            "properties" : {
              "cltseqnum" : {
                "type" : "long",
                "store" : true
              },
              "email1" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "store" : true,
                "analyzer" : "standardAnalyzer"
              }
            }
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "store" : true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "provided_name" : "hibernatemastersearchindex",
        "creation_date" : "1534838340085",
        "analysis" : {
          "filter" : {
            "standardAnalyzer_PatternReplaceFilterFactory" : {
              "all" : "true",
              "pattern" : "([^a-zA-Z0-9\\.])",
              "type" : "pattern_replace",
              "replacement" : " "
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : {
            "standardAnalyzer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "word_delimiter",
                "lowercase",
                "standardAnalyzer_PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
              ],
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "Douqy81VQ7mLX-VWiFYAdQ",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "6030299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Two entities are :**

**HibernateMasterSearch  (which is to be updated)**

```
@Entity
@Indexed(index = "HibernateMasterSearchIndex")
public class HibernateMasterSearch {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;


    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    @IndexedEmbedded(prefix = "clt0100_")
    private Basclt0100TO basclt0100TO;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    @IndexedEmbedded(prefix = "clt0900_")
    private Basclt0900TO basclt0900to ;
```

**Basclt0900TO  (which will provide the data)**

```
 @OneToOne(mappedBy = "basclt0900TO")
    @ContainedIn
    private HibernateMasterSearch hibernateMasterSearch;    


    public HibernateMasterSearch getHibernateMasterSearch() {
        return hibernateMasterSearch;
    }
    public void setHibernateMasterSearch(HibernateMasterSearch hibernateMasterSearch) {
     this.hibernateMasterSearch = hibernateMasterSearch;
    }
```

**Basclt0100TO  (which will provide the data)**

```
@OneToOne
@ContainedIn
private HibernateMasterSearch hibernateMasterSearch;    


public HibernateMasterSearch getHibernateMasterSearch() {
    return hibernateMasterSearch;
}
public void setHibernateMasterSearch(HibernateMasterSearch hibernateMasterSearch) {
    if(hibernateMasterSearch != null) {
        hibernateMasterSearch.setBasclt0100TO(this);
    }
    this.hibernateMasterSearch = hibernateMasterSearch;
}
```

**Hibernate HBM for HibernateMasterSearch**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="com.csc.pt.svc.data.to.HibernateMasterSearch" table="HibernateMasterSearch">
         <id name="id" type="bphx.c2ab.hibernate.NullSafeLong" column="ID">
            <generator class="identity" />
         </id>
        </class>

  </hibernate-mapping>
```

**Creating Initial Indexes**

```
private void createInitialIndex() {
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.current().getSession("");
        FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session.getSession());
        try {

            fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Other than the above code, I'm not using the fulltextsearch session anywhere in my code.

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexmanager">elasticsearch</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.host">http://127.0.0.1:9200</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.index_schema_management_strategy">drop-and-create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.required_index_status">yellow</property>
```

**Code to save A/Basclt0100**

```
public static DBAccessStatus insert(Basclt0100TO basclt0100TO) {
    DBAccessStatus status = new DBAccessStatus();
    try {
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.current().getSession("BASCLT0100");
        if (Util.get(session, basclt0100TO, basclt0100TO.getId()) != null) {
            status.setSqlCode(DBAccessStatus.DB_DUPLICATE);
        } else {
            if (session.contains(basclt0100TO)) {
                session.evict(basclt0100TO);
            }
            LocalDateTime currentDate = LocalDateTime.now();
            Soundex soundex = new Soundex();    
            basclt0100TO.setPhnclient(soundex.encode(basclt0100TO.getClientname()));
            basclt0100TO.setPhnfirst(soundex.encode(basclt0100TO.getFirstname()));

            session.save(basclt0100TO);
            session.flush();
        }
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        status.setException(ex);
    }
    return status;
}
```

The same way B/Basclt0900 and C/Basclt0300 is persisted to database.

Should I persist these to ES DB at the same time. Not sure of how to handle/persist data in such a way that the composite index should get updated with the changes done on DB tables/indexes involved in composite index.

Comment: Not sure mixing HBM mapping with annotation mapping is a great idea, you might want to switch to annotations only, just to check there isn't any problem related to mixing the two approaches. You should also check your logs for warnings or errors, and check that the entity actually gets updated in your database (if it isn't, it's not a Hibernate Search problem, but a Hibernate ORM one). Please show us the code you execute to modify the entities and the code used to create the entity manager and open/commit the transaction (if Spring or some JEE container does that for you, just mention it).

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
For your queries:
1)I'm not receiving any errors on initial index creation and nor on adding a new record to DB. Also, the new record is successfully added to DB and to the corresponding index(e.g. Basclt0100), but the same is not updating under the HibernateMasterSearchIndex.
2)I'm not explicitly/manually updating the Index, its I believe handled internally by Hibernate Search ORM. Added the configuration code in my question.

Comment: Please provide the code you're using to update your entity. It's very likely that the problems lies there, for example if you're not updating both sides of the association like [this other user](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3258).

Comment: Thank You @YoannRodière , I'm attaching the code under the original question.
Further, I'm using the hibernate session to persist data to DB, do you suggest that at the time of persisting data to DB, I should create a fulltextsesstion session and persist the same data to ES DB.
Also, my objects are persisted through different DAO methods and with in a flow, Like First A is persisted, Then B and Then C. So, do I have to use the same objects for adding to parent before persisting. 
In short, all the three are persisted in a sequence, how should i handle that.

Comment: @YoannRodière , Please see if you can provide ur views.

Comment: "I should create a fulltextsesstion session and persist the same data to ES DB" => No, definitely not. "all the three are persisted in a sequence, how should i handle that." => Frankly, I don't know what to say. You're very obviously using advanced features or Hibernate ORM, such as having your own named sessions, evicting entities manually, and so on. Someone in your company knows how your application should work. This person should be able to solve your problem. All I can tell you is: make sure to update your entities consistently: if `A.b` is updated, you must update `B.a`.

Comment: Thanks @YoannRodière , Made it work after analyzing the relationships between our tables. As our tables has non relational mappings, These non relational logic was giving me hard time to implement this. 

In a pure relational mappings/tables this should work fine. Without any tweaking of fultextsession. As I had to make a call to flushToIndexes() for one of the table, post its update. Update was not triggering the composite index(index ontaining A + B +C data) update.